# Getting service worker scope inside fetch event listener

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I want to access my service worker's scope inside of a fetch event listener. My planned workaround was to use `window.location.host`, but `window` isn't available inside the service worker. I also tried using ServiceWorkerRegistration.scope ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/scope)), which would return the value I want, but this also isn't accessible inside the fetch event handler.

I'm hoping there's something similar to `event.scope` (available in the registration handler), but for fetch handlers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging around in Chrome dev tools, I found the variable I was looking for: `self.location.host`. This references the ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, which has a property of 'location'.

I found a similar usage in the Google Chrome team's [example service worker](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/basic/) using self.location.origin instead:

```
// Skip cross-origin requests, like those for Google Analytics.
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don''t know if the specification is more recent than this post, but the actual way to get the scope of a service worker is to use:

```
let scope = self.registration.scope;
```

That will return the scope specified to the service worker. I had to deal with this in my service worker since we have several applications on the same site that could potentially use or not use the serviceworker - depending on the developer's wishes to do so.

Comment: thanks. this was the one I was looking for.